# Select random winner with percentages

Tags: javascript

I would want to select a random winner from about 2 - 10 players.
Every player have precent chance to win. Someone have 50% and someone 10%.

Let's say we have 2 players. One player have 20% and other have 80%. How do I select winner between these two?.

Players are in array

```
var players = {
    player1: {
        chance: 20 //%
    }
    player2: {
        chance: 80 //%
    }
}

//Select winner from json
```

Comment: Randomly draw a number between 1 and 100. If it's 1-20, Player1 wins. If it's 21-100, player two wins. Also, you defined `player1` twice.

Comment: random function with what Santi just said

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming the percentages all add up to 100)

You would first have to order the players. Then take a random number from 1 to 100, and find out which player that random number falls under.

For example:

```
// Modified json to array so we can easily loop through them
// If you would like help turning the json to an array, I can provide code for that upon request
var players = [
    {
        chance: 20
    },
    {
        chance: 40
    },
    {
        chance: 40
    }
];

// Generate random number
var perc = Math.random() * 100; // between 0 and 99.999~
// Save where we are in the percentage
var currentPerc = 0;

// Loop through the players and check who the random number chose
for ( var pID = 0; pID < players.length; pID++ ) {

    // Check if the current player we are looking at has won
    if (perc < (players[pID].chance + currentPerc)) {
        alert("PLAYER " + (pID + 1) + " HAS WON.");
        // Do player winning code here
        break; // break out of the loop, we're done
    } else {
        currentPerc += players[pID].chance;
    }
}
```

In the above example, imagine that the random number chose 45 (0.45 * 100 since math.random gives us 0.0 to 0.99~).
This would mean that player 2 won

```
 0 to  20 = Player 1 wins
21 to  60 = Player 2 wins
61 to 100 = Player 3 wins
```

Using 45 as the random number chosen The first iteration, we check if player 1 has won. He has not, so we add player 1's percentage to the "current percentage".

Then in the second iteration we check player 2. Since 45 < (20 + 40), player 2 has won chosen. We alert that he has won and will do some code for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var players = [20,5,15,40,20];
var getWinner = function(players){
  var random = Math.random();
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
    sum+= players[i]/100;
    if(random<= sum) return i;
  }
}
```

Returns the number of the player(index 0) who wins